# Failed to complete Gradle execution (new project) - java home different

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I downloaded Android Studio version [build 135.1653844] and created a new project. I am getting an error:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution.
Cause:
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. 
Context mismatch: Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\gargn\.gradle\daemon,pid=1000,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=9a6c3945-1d55-46d7-897b-4ed84a5707bb,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\gargn\.gradle\daemon,pid=1664,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

My Java home is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45` and I could not find any setting where I am using the `jre` path. I searched in all text files and could not find `jre` path as shown in the error above.

Comment: I uninstalled Android studio and reinstalled. I also removed all other versions of JDK, updated environment variable, but I still see the same error. Any guesses what could be problem?

Answer (score 6):

Though I did not find the root cause where the different javaHomes have been taken from, at least I found a workaround that worked for me:

Try setting the following in your `gradle.properties` (either in `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\` or in your project build dir):

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre
```

Comment: I tried this, but it just gave a different error. However, changing it to `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.X.X` worked. Note the forward slashes, and that I removed the jre at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer for people looking for a solution:

In my case, I did not have any 32 bit JVMs installed, so I ran IntelliJ in 64 bit mode instead, and everything worked fine after I set my `IDEA_JVM_64` environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the jre from the installation file of inttellij, but when I tried to run intellij, i said that I tried to run a 32bit version of intellij, but no jre for 32bit was found, then I when to the intellij installation directory and run a 64bit version, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Bit Late,But will be helpful for someone,

For me the problem was solved by uninstalling all jdks and installing only one and setting JAVA_HOME for that jdk in my case

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40
```

Thats All

Answer (score 0):

This error appear most likely downloading applications (such as Oracle, Application servers...) that include java version or installing another JDK/JRE.

I managed to solve the this problem by deleting/renaming all JDK/JRE and forders and only keep one and only one JDK folder and contains JRE folder inside.

also I put the JDK path into JAVA_HOME and path vatiables and remove any other JDK/JRE paths from the environment variables.

After that reset the JDK home in your IDE.

Regards,
Mohammed Kharma

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by renaming Info.plist and version.plist to Info.plist.old and version.plist.old in /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents folder on Mac.

Executed

> mv Info.plist Info.plist.old | mv version.plist version.plist.old

in folder mentioned above. Then I just run Intellij and things were working fine. Probably, it would be possible to fix this by renaming only one of these files but I haven't tested it. After fixing it I haven't rename files back to Info.plist and version.plist. Should I?

After this fix, I also created idea.properties file in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2 and added line gradle.java.home=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)