# Gradle Error - The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected. Java home is different

Tags: java, android, gradle

I updated to the latest build and repeatedly get this error when trying to 
refresh my project:

```
Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than
expected.  Java home is different.  Expecting: 'D:\Program 
Files\Android\Android Studio\jre' but was: 'C:\Program   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
<a href="open.project.structure">Open JDK Settings</a>
```

I updated my gradle.properties to point to both D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre and C:\Program files\java\jdk1.8.0.92, forward slash instead and same results.

Comment: Not sure but it looks like your gradle daemon was perhaps started using the older jre (D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre) and now that doesn't exist anymore.  Try running gradle --stop from command line and then re-attempt

Comment: gradle isnt running and rebooted the computer and came up with the same message.  I also tried another java version installed and same thing appeared

Comment: here's another stackoverflow question with several answers you could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245738/failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-new-project-java-home-different

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop all gradle proccesses at the task manager, close all android studios and all programs that could use gradle or call

```
gradle --stop
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the following in your gradle.properties (either in $HOME/.gradle/ or in your project build dir):

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Except the question is using Windows