# Android Studio Error,

Tags: android, android-studio

When I launch an Android Studio Project I get this Error

```
Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: 'D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre' but was: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
Open JDK Settings
```

But my JDK file is the same as the expected file location, as you can see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb0kA.jpg)

Edit: Now I'm getting a new error

`Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html`

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the path in the picture to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101`

Comment: When I try to change it, it changes back to 'D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre after i hit okay

Comment: Now its saying its an invalid directory

Comment: you need to install the latest Java JDK, it will install to your C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\ directory. Change the path to this the jdk package that installs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck the **Use Embedded JDK** then change the path **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101"**

Comment: That's what I did

Comment: Try "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin"

Comment: Try changing the backslashes to forward slashes. "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_101". Try to check this post as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245738/failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-new-project-java-home-different

Answer (score 0):

Please click File-->Project Structrue ... --> SDK Location -->JDK location

Replace `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home` to
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101` 
As show below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please click File-->Project Structrue ... --> SDK Location -->JDK location

Then, type this in the box !!

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152

'jdk1.8.0_152' could be different depending on the version of jdk.

This worked perfectly for the problem that had lasted for 2 weeks !!!

i hope this works for someone who suffers from the error ^^